# AssemblyLoadContext.Unload does not unload a Wpf Library

Tags: wpf, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, assembly-loading, domainunload

I am writing here the same [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3816) posted on Github since I don't see much traffic there recently.

- .NET Core Version: 3.1.9 and .Net 5
- Windows version: 10.0.18363
- Does the bug reproduce also in WPF for .NET Framework 4.8?: AssemblyLoadContext not supported

I am trying to load and unload on demand a Wpf App library (and all the related dependencies). Everything works, but none of the assemblies get unloaded when calling the Unload method.
If I replace the Wpf library with a .Net Core library containing a few sample methods, I can see the library removed from VS Modules window after a couple of GC iterations.

If I'm not wrong I should expect AssemblyLoadContext to load WpfLibrary and related dependencies (PresentationCore, PresentationFramework etc), but WpfLibrary is the only one loaded. All the other dependencies seems be loaded in the default context. May be that I misunderstood how it works, but to me seems that the framework dependencies prevent the unloading.

Also I am not sure if the problem I am reporting is related to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13226) and/or [this](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/1764).

I attached a sample project which is structured like this:

*Project 1 (MainApp, a console project with added System.Windows.Forms reference to enable message pump)*

```
class Program
{
        class WpfAppAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
        {
            public WpfAppAssemblyLoadContext() : base(true) { }
            protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName) => null;
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining),]
        public static void TestRun()
        {
            var context  = new WpfAppAssemblyLoadContext();
            var assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath($"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\WpfLibrary.dll");
            var inst     = (IProxy) assembly.CreateInstance("WpfLibrary.MainWindow");
            inst.ShowWindow();
            inst.CloseWindow();
            context.Unload();
            assembly = null;
            context  = null;
            inst     = null;
        }

        [STAThread,]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestRun();
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }

            Application.Run();
        }
}
```

*Project 2 (ProxyInterface)*

```
namespace ProxyInterface
{
    public interface IProxy
    {
        void ShowWindow();
        void CloseWindow();
    }
}
```

*Project 3 (a regular wpf library with implementation of interface in Project 2 )*

```
namespace WpfLibrary
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, IProxy
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       public void ShowWindow() { Show();}
       public void CloseWindow() { Close();}
    }
}
```

[UnloadWpfLibrary.zip](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/files/5543910/UnloadWpfLibrary.zip)
(Solution file inside "MainApp" folder)

**Further updates:**
DotNet team added the issue to "[Future Milestone](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/milestone/2)", therefore I have to deduce that they recognized this as a bug. I have no idea on when we will see Wpf working with AssemblyLoadContext.
Seems to be that there is a [workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13226#issuecomment-523888788) which involve splitting the target assembly into two separate assemblies. I attached the project with the suggested modifications and this time one of the two assemblies is unloaded, but all of the others are still loaded included WpfLibrary.

[UnloadWpfLibraryWithWorkaround.zip](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/files/5557080/UnloadWpfLibraryWithWorkaround.zip)

I think that for me it's time to give up and recur to IPC (named pipes) although I am not sure if this could be a valid replacement.
May be I missed something and someone more expert can do further progress and attach here the project with the correct modifications, it would be of great benefit for all the users that want to use ALC to load and unload WPF.
It would be a total of 4 projects just to load and unload a wpf assembly on demand and this is not exactly clean, but if the final result is the same it would be acceptable.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. dotnet+core 5.0 is out recently and means development to 3.xx is possibly halted, that might be why no one around. may you try your project with that and see if problem persist?

Comment: Hello and thanks for warm welcome!

Comment: integrate parts of these comments you wrote as further explanation to your main post. this way other members can see what else have you tried, without checking here in the comments.
and sorry, by the way, I am not yet this much into dotnet so cant help to solve it.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and added new details. It should be more clean now. If you think there is more cleaning I can do just let me know. Many thanks!